# Generating page information depending on variable selected

Tags: html, css

I am building a site with a  select tag that has all 50 states. I want to be able to have a page generated for each state selected rather than having to write 50 separate pages. Any ideas on how I would accomplish  this? Thank you.

Comment: are you using any server side code or strictly client side html/javascript?

Comment: right now I am only using html and js, however, I could use anything. Whatever works best.

Comment: Is there a lot of data you want to display per state? How many states do you foresee the average visitor to view?

Comment: if the user selects new york, I want the heading to change to new york and some body text will change according to what complies with new york. If the user selects california, the page should load with the header california and the body text will say somethign about california. something along those lines

Comment: similar to this site, http://us.cibt.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either load all data on page load, or via ajax, and only show the data for the current state,

or if you have a server side database/data source to pull the data from you could also just have the page deliver data for a specific state, defined by a query/GET variable, the URL would look something like:

http://mysite.com/myPage.aspx?state=ca

or

http://mysite.com/myPage.php?state=az

When the page is requested you can then have your server page populate the correct data for the current state, which would then be sent over to the client.

Generally speaking I would lean toward the server side solution, especially if your visitors will likely only visit a handful of states then there's no reason to load ALL states data. On the flip side if the data for each state is very minimal it might not make much different either way.

**EDIT**

I'm not aware of any specific tutorials on the web, but since this encompasses putting a few things together I'll tell you the topics that might be useful in accomplishing this.

Depending on your level of knowledge of php, or c#, or other chosen language for your server side part, research the following topics:

1. Read a Get variable
2. Switch case statements
3. Add variable value into parts of html, or concatenation of html strings
4. Optionally various database topics, (if you don't want to hard code
   data into your code)

For example, your server side php page could look something like this (untested code):

```
<?php
switch($_GET["state"]) {
  case "ca":
    $pageTitle = "California";
    $pageContent = "stuff about CA";
    break;
  case "az":
    $pageTitle = "Arizona";
    $pageContent = "stuff about a really hot state";
    break;
    ...
}

....

echo '<h1>' . $pageTitle . '</h1>' . '<p>' . $pageContent . '</p>'; 

?>
```

Along with that you'd want to handle when the visitor selects a different state, and upon selection of a state load the correct page. With jQuery you could do something with the [change() method](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

in your html body declare you drop down list (select input) with id="stateSelectDropDown", then in your javascript (untested code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#stateSelectDropDown").change(funciton() {
      window.location = "nameOfThisPage.php?state=" + $(this).val();
    });
  }
</script>
```

I apologize for any typos or bad syntax, I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I understand how it works. Thank you, is there an example anywhere on the web that I could look at to better understand. Maybe a tutorial.